# How to pass variables to another function in another module

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python and I'm running into some trouble passing variables to a function in a new module/program I wrote.

I'm working with 2 separate programs/modules here: `xmlgen.py` and `JobHandler.py`. Jobhandler has to pass variables from one of it's functions to a function in xmlgen *(so that `xmlgen.py` can generate an xml document based on the variables in `JobHandler.py`)*.

Here is the function in `xmlgen.py`:

```
from lxml import etree
from Faxer import coverPage, ourOrg, ourPhonenum, ourFaxnum, emailAddr, 
sendReceipt, webAddr, comments

def generateXml(destOrg, destFax, cliName, casenum, attachments, errEAddr, comment, destName):
    #xml file structure
    root = etree.Element('schedule_fax')

    #***
    #irrelevant xml stuff
    #***

    grandchild_recipient_name = etree.Element('name')
    grandchild_recipient_name.text = cliName
    child_recipient.append(grandchild_recipient_name)

    #more similar xml fields with the other variables used
```

Here's the function I made in the main `JobHandler.py` program, to pass variables as arguments from a previous function to `generateXml()` in xmlgen module. The arguments *(job.destOrg, etc.)* were defined previously in the main jobhandler program, in an earlier function.

```
def createXml(self, job):
    xmlgen.generateXml(job.destOrg, job.destFax, job.cliName, job.casenum, job.files, job.staffEmail, job.comment, job.destName)
```

Now when I run this, the xml document is not created. I know it works, because when I remove the function from xmlgen.py and just run it, it creates a blank xml doc properly. So I suspect I'm not calling the function properly. Is there something I'm not doing that's necessary to actually CALL the function?

Comment: It will be greate if you'll provide us where you actually call `createXml()`.

Comment: Well I suspected that to be my problem. I'm not actually calling it and I don't know where or how I can do so. When I place a "createXml() anywhere in the jobhandler program I get "createXml is missing 2 required positional arguments, self and job". And I know I can't import each other to each other

Comment: I should add, that I don't exactly fully understand what the self and job arguments are for. I inherited this program and the guy quit. I just copied those from all of the other functions which do work to pass the variables in the same way for other purposes

Comment: function won't be executed if you don't call it. I think it's more than obvious, so everything you've described in your question is not needed. Question you've posted in comments are too general and unclear. If you can't find entry point - ask previous developer to point you.

Comment: Well he quit. My question is HOW would you go about calling that function? I said when I place createXml(), it tells me that 2 positional arguments are missing (self and job).

Comment: If function has `self` argument, normally it's a method of some object *(self is a reference to this object)*. Try to read some tutorials about python basics if you have troubles in calling functions.

Comment: Looks like `createXml` is an instance method. You would call it with `instance_name.createXml(job_object)`.